# PDF/iText : replace font defs

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (Java lib) to process an already created PDF file.

What I would like to achieve is to replace fonts that are metric-compatible with a PDF base font with that PDF base font. This would make the PDF more "compliant" and potentially also smaller.

Here's how it would go:

- Loop through the fonts used in the PDF.
- If font is metric-compatible
  with a PDF base font then replace font name with that font (but maintain the PDF resource name, e.g. `/F13`, so that we do not need to touch any text
  objects). Since iText embeds in its jar the AFM files for the PDF
  base fonts I'm assuming that iText actually has enough knowledge to
  make this assesment. I would probably have to look at
  serif/sans-serif and monotype flags as well to know if I should swap
  in Helvetica, Times or Courier.
- Further if metric-compatible: Remove
  any font embeds for that font. (since we've replaced with a PDF base
  font there's no need to embed anything .. size matters!)

An example:

An existing PDF file uses "Calibri", "Arial" and "Times". Here's how each of those should be handled.

- Calibri. This font doesn't have a metric-compatible cousin among the PDF base fonts so processing for this font resource will be skipped.
- Arial. This font has a metric-compatible cousin among the PDF base fonts, namely "Helvetica". The name of the font resource (attribute `BaseFont` I suppose) will be changed to "Helvetica" and any potential embeds will be removed.
- Times. This font is already a PDF base font. Skip processing. (we may consider unembedding here if there's something to unembed, but I already know how to do that so not part of the question)

I basically get stuck on the step which is to determine metric-compatibility. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(Note: An answer based on iText 5.x is perfectly ok as I feel the recent iText 7 is still somewhat undocumented)

#### UPDATE

As pointed out a number of checks would need to be carried out in addition in order to do a safe replacement:

1. Font encoding compatibility. Not really a problem for me as fonts in the documents I'll be processing will be using WinAnsiEncoding.
2. Available chars in font. Not really a problem for me as I'll only be processing documents that use only ISO 8859-1 chars. Furthermore: If the PDF contains an embedded subset of a font then I'll have easily accessible knowledge about exactly which chars is used in the document for that font.

I'm sure I can figure out to check for both these conditions. (I'm blissfully naive)

I'm not trying to do a general tool. I know where the PDF's I'll be processing comes from. In any case I guess it is possible to have enough information from the PDF to skip the font substitution if it can't be determined that the substitution will be "safe".

Comment: There are a number of problems with your task. **a** you in particular have embedded fonts on your mind, but embedded fonts more often than not use an ad-hoc encoding, and the mapping glyphs <-> characters does not need to be explicitly given in the PDF. **b** the standard 14 fonts (i.e. your base fonts) are only required to support a fairly limited character set. **c** what do you exactly mean by *metric-compatible*? Your example compatible pair Arial and Helvetica, for example, does not have a single set of metrics.

Comment: With Adobe Reader the standard fonts are shipped, look in Resource/Font. Hence if you find nothing in PDF/iText, you can use Font processing software. For instance compare the glyphs of some letters (i, g, a, W) of all standard fonts with the actual fonts or such. _(Of course those fonts are property of Adobe.)_

Comment: @mkl. Thanks. By "metric-compatible" I mean fonts that can be drop-in replacements for another font. An example: Arial has been deliberately created to be metric-compatible with Helvetica,i.e. the two can safely be swapped for one another without letters moving around or things starting to look odd.

Comment: But keep in mind even a bog standard Arial has a far larger character set than ol' trusty Type 1 Helvetica. The same goes for Times New Roman vs. Times.

Comment: @RadLexus. I've added an "UPDATE" to the question.

Comment: @peterh Considering your **update** you seem to have many positive side conditions which seem to make your task do-able. So it looks like you have a very homogeneous pool of PDF files to work on; can you share an example file?

Comment: @mkl. Sorry. Can't do that.